# Authoring Gradle task with int[] input property

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I am authoring a Gradle task that needs to work on an array of integers (dispatching a job for each value).

I don't understand how to properly use `Property<T>` to accept a Groovy array syntax.

The following does not work

Inside Task.java

```
/**
 * Element IDs to download
 */
@Input
protected abstract Property<Integer[]> getTaxonomyElementIds();
```

Inside build.gradle

```
taxonomyElementIds = [200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208]
```

Error

```
Cannot set the value of task ':downloadMasterDb' property 'taxonomyElementIds' of type [Ljava.lang.Integer; using an instance of type java.util.ArrayList.
```

The following workaround works, but I prefer a cleaner Groovy syntax

```
    taxonomyElementIds = [200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208].toArray(Integer[]::new)
```

I also tried to change the type of the property to `List<Integer>` (which essentially doesn't change my task code) but doesn't work.

How can I change my property in order to accept the Groovy array/list syntax?

Comment: I wouldn't expect `taxonomyElementIds = [200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208]` to work because that is an `ArrayList`.  Does `taxonomyElementIds = [200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208] as int[]` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ListProperty<Integer>`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/provider/ListProperty.html) instead:

```
plugins {
    id("java")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

abstract class MyTask extends DefaultTask {

    @Input
    protected abstract ListProperty<Integer> getTaxonomyElementIds();

    @TaskAction
    void generate() {
        taxonomyElementIds.get().each {
            println it
        }
    }

}

tasks.register("myTask", MyTask) {
    taxonomyElementIds = [200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208]
}
```

Output of the above:

```
> Task :myTask
200
201
202
203
204
205
206
207
208
```